# InDesign: horizontal to vertical spread

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I have a horizontal spread of pages (1 and 2 side by side). I need to get page 2 at the bottom of page 1.

How can I achieve this? I have tried manually drag, but as these are master pages applied, it's getting difficult to move them to along with content.

Answer (score 2):

The actual pages do not rotate, but your view of them while working can.

Select both pages in the spread. Right click to get the below options. Page Attribute > Rotate Spread View > 90˚ CW.  You can see the little rotate icon next to the spread now that says it is rotated. Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no vertical spreads built-in as far as i know. You will have to create a new document with a page size of 2x the height. For example if the page size is A4, start a new document without spreads and set the page size to 210x594mm.

Or, you could try [this workaround](https://indesignsecrets.com/vertical-master-page-spreads.php), however the post is quite old and not sure if this works in recent versions of InDesign. Some comments there saying it does not work with ID CC.

If you're making a calendar or some other item with top binding, note you may actually not need to prepare this vertical page flow in InDesign. Just sending single non-facing pages to the printer could be enough. It will then be their job to set the machines so that the product ends up with a top binding.